# Calculate values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following dictionary:

```
food_calories = {"Burger": 400, "Ice Cream": 350, "Cake": 640, "Chicken": 400, "Rice": 250, "Salad": 40, "Fanta": 170, "Coke": 200, "Beef": 350}
```

How can I calculate the sum of some values of the dictionary? E.g. Ice Cream", "Chicken", "Beef") #=> 1100

I only get errors and I'm stuck in setting up the function.

```
min_calories = min(zip(food_calories.values(), food_calories.keys()))
max_calories = max(zip(food_calories.values(), food_calories.keys()))
print("min_calories:",min_calories)
print("max_calories:",max_calories)

values = food_calories.values()
total = sum(values)
print(total)

def food_calories_sum():
  for k in food_calories:
    return k
```

Comment: I don't understand your question... could you provide an example of what is the expected output and what is the current output?

Comment: "I only get errors" - the code you posted works fine and doesn't raise any errors

Comment: You are already calculating the sum `total = sum(values)`, I dont understand what do you need??

Comment: I want to calculate just some of the values and not all of them as I did. How can I call it that I only get the calories sum of a few values?

Comment: what do you mean by "some of the values" .. is that an input to the function? the list of keys?

Comment: I want to calculate it in that way that I can put in some keys e.g.  Ice Cream", "Chicken", "Beef" and get the sum of the calories as a result which are 1100

Comment: check the answer i wrote and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it helped a lot! Thank you so much. I forgot about using .get instead of a for loop

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
l = ["Ice Cream", "Chicken", "Beef"]

def food_calories_sum(l):
    return sum([food_calories.get(i,0) for i in l])

food_calories_sum(l)
```

```
1100
```

You can replace the `food_calories.get(i,0)` with `food_calories[i]` but if you pass an item that doesn't exist in the `food_calories` dictionary it will throw an error.

Instead, `food_calories.get(i,0)` returns 0 as default value if key is not found, therefore only returning sum for items that exist and doing some exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of each key by using this syntax: `food_calories['item']`, where `item` is some key in your dictionary.

This is a sample output where `food_calories` is the dict you defined in your post:

```
>>> food_calories['Rice'] + food_calories['Burger']
650
```